# Missing something in the regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use this regex

```
art\..*[A-Z].*\s
```

to extract the text in bold here

> some text bla **art. 100 of Important_text** other text bla

Basically, I would like to extract all the text that follow this pattern:

```
*art.* *number* *whatever* *first word that starts in uppercase*
```

But it's not working as expected. Any suggestion?

Comment: It will be either `r'\bart\..*?\b[A-Z]\S*'` or `r'\bart\..*?\b[A-Z]\w*'`

Comment: *"But it's not working as expected. Any suggestion?"* - My suggestion is to tell us what you mean with "not working as expected".

Comment: You can use `\bart\.\D*\d+[^A-Z]*[A-Z]\S+` https://regex101.com/r/mKZfwK/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match `art.` then match until the first digits and then match until the first occurrence of an uppercase char.

```
\bart\.\D*\d+[^A-Z]*[A-Z]\S*
```

The pattern matches

- `\bart\.` Match `art.` preceded by a word boundary
- `\D*\d+` Match 0+ times a non digit, followed by 1+ digits
- `[^A-Z]*` Match 0+ times any char except A-Z
- `[A-Z]\S*` Match a char A-Z followed by optional non whitespace chars.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7t4AaC/1)

If the word has to start with A-Z you can assert a whitespace boundary to the left using `(?<!\S)` before matching an uppercase char A-Z.

```
\bart\.\D*\d+[^A-Z]*(?<!\S)[A-Z]\S*
```

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
\bart\..*?\d+.*?[A-Z]\w*
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/y4tfZ9/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
\b           ##mentioning word boundary here.
art\.        ##Looking for word art with a literal dot here.
.*?\d+       ##Using non-greedy approach for matching 1 or more digits.
.*?[A-Z]\w*  ##Using non-greedy approach to match 1 capital letter followed by word characters.
```

Comment: I suggest using `\S*` at the end; otherwise, your regex will fail for something like `some text bla art. 100 of This-Is-Important_text other text bla`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/m6qKqF/1)